# Interop.RDPCOMAPILib file could not load

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am making an screen sharing C# .Net windows form application so i used Com library , application is working good in visual studio 2013 while compiling but when i used its exe then it shows this error.
"could not load file or assembly 'interop.RDPCOMAPILib, version=1.0.0.0, culture=neautral, publickey token=null or one of its dependencies."
[image]

Kindly give me a solution .
Thanks

Comment: On the same computer you've been working with ?

Comment: i think he is working in the same exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DLL files of COM library should be included in EXE or package you are deploying. Try this and let me know if it works.